# Client-Server application in java not able to recieve all messages sent by the client

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I'm working on a client-server application with two modules:
1). Registry: All servers in the network register their IP and port they are listening to with the registry.
2). Messaging node: These are also servers, which communicate with each other in a round of messages, once they receive the command from the registry. A messaging node will only send messages to 1 node at a time, but may receive from multiple nodes.

The registry sends a list of available (registered) nodes to all other servers, and upon receiving this list, the nodes start exchanging messages with each other.

I was able to get the registry part working, and the nodes are able to register themselves. Also, the nodes successfully receive the nodes list from the registry and able to start exchanging messages. How ever, the messaging nodes are not able to receive all the messages being sent.

Here's the messaging node part:

```
public class MessagingNode  {

    // Constructor
    public MessagingNode(String registryHost, int registryPort)  {
        try  {
            registryHostname = InetAddress.getByName(registryHost).getHostAddress();
        } catch (Exception e)  {
            System.out.println("Can't resolve Registry hostname!");
        }
        registryPortNumber = registryPort;

        // Start the node server
        try  {
            nodeServerSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            System.out.println("Can't start node server!");
        }

        // Store the MessagingNode server port and IP address
        try  {
            nodeIpAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch(Exception e)  {
            System.out.println("Can't get localhost");
        }
        nodePortNumber = nodeServerSocket.getLocalPort();
        //System.out.println("Node Port:"+nodePortNumber);

        // Initialize trackers
        sendTracker = 0;
        receiveTracker = 0;
        sendSummation = 0;
        receiveSummation = 0;
        sending = false;
    }



    // Start the NodeServer to listen for other nodes
    public void startNodeServer()  {
        if(!isRunning)  {
            isRunning = true;
            consoleListener();
            while(MessagingNode.this.isRunning)  {
                Socket clientSocket = null;
                try  {
                    clientSocket = nodeServerSocket.accept();
                    openClient(clientSocket);                       

                } 
                catch(IOException e)  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }


    // Messaging nodes receiving 
    public void openClient(final Socket socket)  {
        Thread clientThread = new Thread()  {
            public void run()  {
                int count = 0;
                try  { 
                    byte[] messagePayload = new byte[64];

                    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
                    //BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));   
                    while(din.read(messagePayload) > -1)  {

                        //count++;

                        int type = InterpretMessage.getMessageType(messagePayload);
                        if(type == MessageTypes.MESSAGING_NODES_LIST)  {
                            trimNodeList(messagePayload);
                            System.out.println("Node list Received!");
                            dataThread();

                        } 
                        else  {         
                            handleIncomingPayload(messagePayload);
                        }
                    }
                    //System.out.println("Input connection closed after :" + count);
                //System.out.println("Listener Closed!");
                //in.close();
                //socket.close();

                }
                catch(Exception e)  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        };
        clientThread.start();
        try  {
                    clientThread.join();
                }
                catch(Exception e)  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


    }

    public void dataThread()    {
        Thread t = new Thread()  {
            public void run()  {
                sendData();
            }
        };
        t.start();
        try  {
            t.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendData()  {
        // pick a node
        int size = messagingNodesList.size();
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * size);
        //System.out.println("Node being contacted:" + messagingNodesList.get(index));
        String details = messagingNodesList.get(index);
        String[] str = details.split(" ");


        try  {
            Socket socket = new Socket(str[0], Integer.parseInt(str[1]));
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            for(int i= 0; i < 5; i++)  {
                CommMessage outgoing = new CommMessage();
                byte[] msg = outgoing.marshall();
                out.write(msg, 0, msg.length);
                System.out.println("Sending number:" + outgoing.number);
                out.flush();
            }
            out.close();
            //closeConnection = true;
        }
        catch(IOException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Remove Node's information
    public void trimNodeList(byte[] incoming)  {
    // Removes the current node's information from the list recieved from registry
    }

    // Update trackers
    public void handleIncomingPayload(byte[] payload)  {
        CommMessage msg = new CommMessage(payload);
        msg.unmarshall();
        System.out.println("Receiving Number:"+msg.number);
        //synchronized(this)  {
            receiveSummation += msg.number;
            receiveTracker += 1;
        //}
    }


    // Console Listener
    public void consoleListener()  {
        Thread listener = new Thread()  {
            public void run()  {
                // listen for keyboard instructions
            }
        };
        listener.start();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        MessagingNode node = new MessagingNode(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        node.connectRegistry();
        node.startNodeServer();
        //node.deregisterNode();
        //node.deregisterNode();
        //node.sendBurst();
        // Launch the console Listener Thread
        // Initiate rounds of messaging

    }
}
```

The problem is somewhere in the receiving portion I'm assuming. I tried using using synchronized on the sendData method as someone pointed out it could be a concurrency issue but it didn't help. I'm still not able to receive all messages. Any insights will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You copied too much text on your question. Can you please trim it down to the relevant parts only?

Comment: I've updated the question. Now it only includes the MessagingNodes pasrt which I'm having a problem with.

Comment: That's still quite extensive. This is a Q&A site where users will help you if you show research/effort. Simply copying your whole class will make it time-consuming to read and interpret. Be more precise -- the individual function(s) and code blocks.

Comment: Updated again. My apologies, this is the first time I'm using this website.

Comment: Hmmm..Helpful community indeed.

Comment: Make sure [you've asked a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and if you consider so, at 75 rep, you [can start a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).